# What is the difference? : in xdg-open in linux and QGIS in window

Tags: qgis, gdal, image, linux, rgb

I made a rgb raster image with using GDAL script in the Linux (Centos7) environment.
When I open the rgb image with xdg-open, it's too dark, but when I open it in the QGIS, it is clear and more beautiful. Why? What's difference? How can I see the image like QGIS in the Linux enviroment. I attached their image.

In the QGIS,
[image]

In the Linux,
[image]

I'm sure the uploaded images came from a same file. I shared the my code below:

```
#!/bin/bash
path="/home/changwan/IMAGE/"
path2="/home/changwan/IMAGE/"

echo -e "ENTER YOUR FILE NAME"
read word
echo "YOUR FILE NAME: $word"

fn=$word

fn2="test"
ext=".tif"
ext2=".tif "


**#RGB COMPOSITIO**N
**#BGRN -> sequence along the wavelength**
**gdal_merge.py** -o $path2$fn2\_rgb3$ext **-separate** $path$fn\_B$ext2\
$path$fn\_G$ext2 $path$fn\_R$ext2\
**-co PHOTOMETRIC=RGB -co COMPRESS=DEFLATE**


**#REORDER THE BANDS**
**gdal_translate** $path2$fn2\_rgb3$ext2 $path2$fn2\_rgb4$ext2 **-b 3 -b 2 -b 1** \
**-co COMPRESS=DEFLATE -co PHOTOMETRIC=RGB**


**#ALGORITHMIC IMAGE ENHANCEMENT**
**gdal_translate** $path2$fn2\_rgb4$ext2 $path2$fn2\_scaled4$ext2 **-scale $Min $Max 0 65535** \
**-exponent 1 -co COMPRESS=DEFLATE -co PHOTOMETRIC=RGB**


**#ALPAH BAND**
**gdalwarp -srcnodata 0 -dstalpha** $path2$fn2\_out2$ext2 $path2$fn2\_out3$ext2
```

This is the main part of my program with the bold to enforce my intention in the script. Just to clarify in this code, I get $Min and $Max values from a rgb raster file by using AWK that I did not upload because It could make the code a little messy.

Is there any way to see the raster image more bright other than xdg-open?

Regards,
Changwan

Comment: If you turn the min-max stretch off from QGIS you will probably see the same dark image.  Your `**#ALGORITHMIC IMAGE ENHANCEMENT**` does not really enhance the image, it is spreading the pixel values to range 0-65535 but computer screen is using values 0-255. If your image viewer cannot do the stretch then use gdal_translate with `-ot Byte` and scale 0-255.

Comment: OK!, I will try. Thanks a million!